# Error compiling CSS asset on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, asset-pipeline, sass

I have a new Ruby on Rails app running on Heroku's Cedar stack.  The app works great locally.  However, when I try to log in to my website, I get the error:

```
Error compiling CSS asset

Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find the file 'reset.scss'
  (in app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:4)
```

My file application.css looks like the following:

```
/**
 *= require_self
 *= require reset.scss
 *= require_tree .
*/
```

And then, in the directory assets/stylesheets, I have the files

```
application.css
reset.scss
dialog.scss
etc
```

The idea is that I want application.css to compile all the css assets together, with the reset.scss file appearing at the top.

Is this a bug in Heroku?  Why would it work perfectly locally but not work on Heroku?

Comment: If you use the usual Rails convention of ".css.scss" extensions (i.e. target language + renderer/source language), you should be able to simply say "require reset", and the asset pipeline should figure it out, I think.

Comment: Have you tried to compile those assets in your development mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following things

- Ensure the the *application.css* is included in your layout file. if not, then add the following css link tag.

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>`

- Rename `reset.scss` to either `reset.css`(if its pure css) OR `reset.css.scss`(if it contains scss markup)
- In your `application.css`, you can just require by `*= require reset`. As per rails convention, file extension of assets is skipped.
- get rid of `require_tree` & require each file explicitly

Lastly, if it still doesn't work. As a workaround, you can enable runtime compile of assets in your `/config/environment/production.rb`.It should only be slow the first time that asset is hit, and therefore compiled. Requests after the initial compilation should be normal speed.

Comment: OK, I did that and it seems to be getting me closer.  However, now I have duplicate CSS and JS files.  The application.css file gets all the css files compiled into one big file (the way I want it).  But the stylesheet_link_tag is being expanded into the following, which means each stylesheet declarations appear twice!  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/reset.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/buttons.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> etc

Comment: Try getting rid of `require_tree` & require each file explicitly . that does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be a local compilation of assets using '**rake assets:precompile**' and then adding them to the project repository.